# Removing IIS Request Filtering

Tags: security, iis, nextcloud, url-rewriting

I'd like a bit of a sanity check (feel free to migrate if I've chosen the wrong site).

**Setup**

I'm hosting (at home) an instance of Nextcloud (think "self hosted Dropbox") running on Ubuntu/Apache.  However, publicly facing I have an instance of IIS acting as a reverse proxy. Nextcloud supports syncing using http requests at `nextcloud.mydomain.com/remote.php/dav/files/[username]`, to which I forward requests by using IIS's "URL Rewrite" feature.

**Problem I "solved"**

By default IIS blocks `GET` requests for a bunch of file types (`.aspx`, `.config`, `.cs`, etc.). While this is normally prudent, since I'm using the site as a file syncing utility, this prevents a bunch of files from being synced.  To get around this I added physical directories (in windows) `/remote.php/dav/files/`, so that I can apply policies in IIS directly to the location that syncing uses.  From here I removed all limitations in "Request Filtering" for `/remote.php/dav/files/`.  Now I can sync as desired.

I've tested files above `/remote.php/dav/files/` and confirmed I am *unable* to perform a `GET` on restricted file types at that level, only at `/remote.php/dav/files/` and below (as intended).

**Other Info**

SSL is being used up to the public facing IIS, but not between IIS and Nextcloud.

**The Question**

Is this setup ok?  Have I inadvertently opened myself up to something I didn't intend to?  Note that security for requests that are forwarded/rewritten to the Nextcloud server are handled by that server.

Comment: I don;t think this is request filtering, but handler mapping. have you disabled the handlers that would normally intercept a GET request for an ASPX and render it as a server-side page, and added a .* handler for files that will processes them the way you want? what IIS roles are installed for Application Development?

Comment: @FrankThomas Since I'm using `URL Rewrite` to reverse proxy to another server, it's definitely `Request Filtering`.  As is, there is no rendering happening on IIS, only forwarding (with filtering happening before that).